# Docker-compose builds app and copy's not inteded directory content specified by dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to containerize two services an socket service and a django application

My file structure is

```
\main file {docker-compose file} 
   \ django application {Dockerfile}
   \ socket app {Dockerfile}
```

When I run `docker build .` it build the image
then when I run `docker-compose build`,
I notice that the socket app and django app are copied to the container instead of only the django application as specified by the Dockerfile.

I get the idea that the Dockerfile is executed in the main directory instead of the django directory?

Here is Dockerfile that is inside the django app application

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3

# Set environment varibles
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code

# Install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy project
COPY . /code/

RUN ls
```

And here is the docker-compose file.
With the usage of the ls command I tried to figure out what happend and the output is that the applications in the main folder are copied instead of the django application.

```
version: '3'
  services:
    db:
      image: postgres:10.1-alpine
      volumes:
        - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    web:
      build: ./django_app
      command: ls /code/
      volumes:
        - .:/code
      ports:
        - 8000:8000
      depends_on:
        - db

  volumes:
    postgres_data:
```

is this intended use or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `volumes:` directive in your `docker-compose.yml` file is hiding literally everything your Dockerfile does.  You'll solve your immediate problem by changing the two directories to match: in the `volumes:` directive, bind-mount `./django_app:/code`.

In a more production-oriented workflow, I'd recommend making your Docker image totally self-contained: make sure it has a `CMD` that runs your application, and do not use `volumes:` to inject your code.  Delete `command:` and `volumes:` from the `docker-compose.yml` and let the image provide its own code and default command.  (To do development, use a Python virtual environment for local code isolation, and make sure all of your tests and a basic hand-run workflow pass before using Docker for anything.)